# JS function of representing array elements in ASCII

Tags: javascript, ascii

```js
function translateInWord(mas){
  mas = [].concat(...mas);
  for (let i = 0; i < mas.length; i++){
    mas[i] = String.fromCharCode(mas[i]);
  }
  return mas;
}
console.log(translateInWord([[6,8,13],[5,3,0]]));
```

I want the program to show me every letter in ASCII from the array 'mas` (that is, it should turn out ['G','I','N','F','D','A'])

Comment: ASCII code for `A` is 65, not 0. Perhaps you mean the offset in the English alphabet rather than ASCII?

Comment: ^ then `97` would also be the offset in the English alphabet, just lowercase. Better get away from ASCII at all and redefine this problem. The offsets relative to a specific `const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`

Comment: @Thomas I didn't mean any computer encoding. The English alphabet only has 26 letters, with uppercase/lowercase not being considered different letters, so 97 would be off limits. ASCII has seemingly become a generic idiom for any numeric encoding of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a 0-indexed representation of the alphabet (0 -> A, ..., 25 -> Z).

[`fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) is taking UTF-16 code units as parameters.

If you look at an [UTF-16 table](https://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2?val=0%2C255), the decimal representation of `A` is `65` and the following 25 code units are corresponding to the other capital letters of the alphabet up to `Z`.

So you just need to add `65` to `mas[i]` to get its corresponding letter :

```js
function translateInWord(mas){
  mas = [].concat(...mas);
  for (let i = 0; i < mas.length; i++){
    mas[i] = String.fromCharCode(mas[i] + 65);
  }
  return mas;
}
console.log(translateInWord([[6,8,13],[5,3,0]]));
```

Comment: You should include some explanation in answers, not just code.

Comment: Agreed with @xdumaine, what kind of offset is it? Why it's equal to `65`? Answer code is not obvious.